# ROS 2 Admin Privileges on Windows 10

Tags: ros, ros2, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering why Windows 10 needs administrator privileges to build and run ROS 2, and if this could be changed with a patch?

> To build ROS 2 you will need a Visual Studio Command Prompt (“x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019”) running as Administrator.

This is detailed in the build settings, but it doesn't link to an explanation of why.

> Note that the first time you run any executable you will have to allow access to the network through a Windows Firewall popup.

This, also from the build guide, is my best guess as to why, but I'm asking because I'm not sure.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330552/ros-2-admin-privileges-on-windows-10/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2019-08-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-08-12**:
Is this the explanation you are looking for: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Windows-Development-Setup/#patch-exe-opens-a-new-command-window-and-asks-for-administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is at least one issue: `patch.exe` seems to require running in administrator mode. There is more context in [this `rviz_ogre_vendor` ticket](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/543) and a [note about it](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Windows-Development-Setup/#patch-exe-opens-a-new-command-window-and-asks-for-administrator) on the Windows development setup page.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0